# Updating table using PHP is overriding CSS formatting

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I am using PHP to call data from a Microsoft SQL Database. That functionality is working, however when PHP updates the table's data it is overriding some of the formatting. One big specification I wanted was to have a max-height of 400px and once it crosses that the table becomes scroll-able.

Some context: I am running this on a local PHP server.

I have tried adding !important tags but that did not work.

```
    <table id = 'tbl' class='table'>
            <thead id = 'heading'>
              <tr>
                <td scope="col" >Applicant ▼</td>
                <td scope="col">Grantee EIN</td>
                <td scope="col">State</td>
                <td scope="col">FAC Accepted Date</td>
                <td scope="col">Expenditures</td>
                <td scope="col">Prior Finding</td>
                <td scope="col">Audit</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <div id = 'scrollbody'>
              <tbody>
                <?php
                $result = array();

                do {
                  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    echo '
                    <tr>
                    <td>'.$row["AUDITEENAME"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["EIN"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["STATE"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["FACACCEPTEDDATE"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["TOTFEDEXPEND"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["PYSCHEDULE"].'</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" oninput=""></td>
                    </tr>
                    ';
                  }
                } while (sqlsrv_next_result($stmt));


                // sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
                // sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnectiokn first

                // echo json_encode($result); //You will get the encoded array variable
                ?>
              </tbody>
            </div>
    </table>
```

```
    #tbl {
      margin: auto;
      top: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 400px;
      position: relative;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(240, 240, 240);
      perspective: 1px;
      border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

What I want to see is a table of 400px height, but instead a table of much longer height is being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are 2 options:

1. Wrap the table in with a wrapper and give the `max-height` to that element. 

   `<div id="table-wrapper">
       <table>
           {Your stuff...}
       </table>
   </div>`
2. Give the thead, tbody a `display: block` property. With which again your CSS styles will come into use.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know how a browser works.

**The browser will not show anything until this steps are made:**

1. Your browser request a file like **html or php** first.
2. Then it will check the styling **(CSS/SCSS)**.
3. Checking for JavaScript.
4. checking for source like an image or other media.

**Only then it will display the page.**

So if you want to style after this process, you will need JavaScript.

**JavaScript** is invented to manipulate or modify the DOM (document object Model).
That means, you can point to an element and style it, remove it, add a new element etc.

For a better format I prefer jQuery.

**jQuery** is another way to code JavaScript. (jQuery = JavaScript, just in another form) jQuery calls the JS library.

Answer (score 0):

you can't set header of a table, a table height is based on his content, if you need a table with a specific height you need to change the display type and add overflow rule:

```
    #tbl {
      margin: auto;
      top: 0px;
      height: 100px;
      max-height: 400px;
      position: relative;
      font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px rgb(240, 240, 240);
      perspective: 1px;
      border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
      display:block;
      overflow:auto;
    }
```

Here a live fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g7fuLhyp/